# how to highlight a text input in react native when it is clicks

Tags: android, react-native

highlight a text input in react native when it is clicks

```
firstNameView:{
        width:'90%',
        height:'80%',
        borderWidth:1,
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        flexDirection:'row',
        marginStart:10,
        marginTop:40,
        marginLeft:10,
        backgroundColor:COLORS.grey,
        borderRadius:5,
        borderColor:COLORS.grey
        
    },
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use Library like [nativebase](https://%5Bhttps://docs.nativebase.io/next/input#page-title%5D)   as it will be easy for you to implement and make changes